# Linkedin login doesnt work SLogin

Tags: authentication, oauth, joomla-extensions, social-media

I have a issue with slogin for Joomla, a plugin to login with ur social media. I already managed to get all the other social media to work but now im stuck with linkedin, I dont get it to work.
it give me the error failed to authentication try it later again.
Im sure the api key and OAuth User Token and both the secrets are filled in like supposed.

Here is a picture of some of te setting most are not filled in because they are not required but maybe i need to fill in one of these to get it work. i tried already some things but they didn't work

[image: settings]

If you need more settings or any other information tell me.
Thanks